# How to add chatter in visual force page

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I am using this code

```
<chatter:feed entityId="{!accountId}"/>
```

to add chatter in salesforce it works but "Log a call" button does not work. can any one help me that to add a chatter in visual force page that will work fine.

```
<chatter:feed entityId="{!accountId}"/>
```

Comment: <chatter:feed entityId="{!accountId}"/>

Comment: Please check in standard view of account whether log a call button works there. will just replicate the feed on standard view

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page > 
    <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/> 
</apex:page>
```

This will display the Chatter feed for the currently logged in user. The entityID here can be the ID of a standard object, custom object, user etc.